# C# unable to move character in ASCII Console game

Tags: c#, oop, console, character, ascii

I have a C# project for school. I am unable to move my character in this ASCII console game. It has to be OO. After I run the code I get this:

[image: Result before pressing left or right.]

After I press left or right I get

[image: this.]

Can someone help me on this? Any help is appreciated.

program.cs:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SuperConsole.Init(50, 44);

        // create the game
        Game game = new Game(30, 30);

        //create objects
        Entity spaceship = new Entity(1, 15, '@', SuperConsoleColor.Cyan); 



        // start the game loop
        RunGameLoop(game);
    }

    protected static void RunGameLoop(Game game)
    {
        SuperConsole.BackgroundColor = SuperConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        SuperConsole.ForegroundColor = SuperConsoleColor.Gray;

        int refreshRate = 20;

        SuperConsole.CursorVisible = false;

        SuperConsole.BackgroundColor = SuperConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        SuperConsole.ForegroundColor = SuperConsoleColor.Gray;
        SuperConsole.Clear();

        Reset(game);

        game.Draw(0.0f);

        SuperConsole.Flush();

        /*
        SuperConsole.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);*/

        while (true)
        {
            while (SuperConsole.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = SuperConsole.ReadKey(true);
                game.OnInput(key.Key);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 / refreshRate);

            Reset(game);
            game.Draw(1.0f / (float)refreshRate);
            SuperConsole.Flush();


        }
    }

    protected static void Reset(Game game)
    {
        SuperConsole.BackgroundColor = SuperConsoleColor.Black;
        SuperConsole.ForegroundColor = SuperConsoleColor.Black;
        SuperConsole.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        for (int y = 0; y < game.GetHeight(); ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < game.GetWidth(); ++x)
            {
                SuperConsole.Write(" ");
            }
            SuperConsole.WriteLine();
        }
        SuperConsole.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    }
}
```

}

game.cs:

```
class Game : Entity
{
    protected int width, height;

    Entity spaceship = new Entity(1, 15, '@', SuperConsoleColor.Cyan);

    public Game(int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {

        // set the size
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;

        // set the window
        Console.WindowWidth = width+1;
        Console.WindowHeight = height+1;
    }

    public int GetWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public int GetHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public void Draw(float dt) 
    {

        SuperConsole.SetCursorPosition(spaceship.GetX(), spaceship.GetY());
        SuperConsole.ForegroundColor = spaceship.GetColour();
        SuperConsole.Write(spaceship.GetChar());
    }



    public void OnInput(ConsoleKey key)
    {
        int redo = 0;
        ConsoleKey pressedKey = key;

        do
        {    
            Console.Clear();

            switch (pressedKey)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    SuperConsole.SetCursorPosition(spaceship.GetX() - 1, spaceship.GetY());
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:

                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:

                    SuperConsole.SetCursorPosition(spaceship.GetX()+1, spaceship.GetY());

                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:

                    break;
            }
        } while (redo == 0);

    }

}
```

}

entity.cs:

```
class Entity 
{
    protected int xPos;
    protected int yPos;

    protected char character;

    protected SuperConsoleColor colour;



    public Entity()
    {
    }

    public Entity(int xPosNew, int yPosNew, char newCharacter, SuperConsoleColor newColour) 
    {
        //define position
        xPos = xPosNew;
        yPos = yPosNew;

        //define character
        character = newCharacter;

        //define colour
        colour = newColour;
    }

    public char GetChar()
    {
        return character;
    }

   public int GetX()
    {
        return xPos;
    }




    public int GetY()
    {
        return yPos;
    }

    public SuperConsoleColor GetColour()
    {
        return colour;
    }




}
```

}

Comment: Look at creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions with big blocks of code asking "debug plz" are not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:

- Within `RunGameLoop(Game game)` you should replace `while (SuperConsole.KeyAvailable)` with `if (SuperConsole.KeyAvailable)`.
- Within `Game.OnInput(ConsoleKey)` you change the cursor position instead of the spaceship position

Also try using breakpoints to Check if the code reaches Game.Draw() and check if the spaceship position and the cursor position are correct.

Also you should get a bit more into C#. 
Instead of

```
public char GetChar()
{
    return character;
}
private character;
```

.Net allows you to use Properties:

```
public char Character
{
    get; private set;
}
```

or

```
public char Character
{
    get { return character; }
}
private character = '@';
```

Hope this helps.

Apart from that: No offense, but this question isn't really what Stackoverflow is for. In future, please be more patient and try to googling debugging tips instead of letting Stackoverflow do the 'dirty work' for you.